# Detecting grey scale issue

Tags: java, image-processing, ocr

I am doing OCR and sometime I have a light text on a dark background. When I encounter this situation I need the program to know that it has to invert the colours. The code I have wrote doesn't work how I want. It is detecting dark colours as light and light colours as dark. Any ideas what I've done wrong?

```
File input = new File("/Users/unknown1/Desktop/t5.png");
BufferedImage imagegrey = ImageIO.read(input);
toGray(imagegrey);

int width = imagegrey.getWidth();
int height = imagegrey.getHeight();
int light = 0;
int dark = 0;
for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
        Color color = robot.getPixelColor(j, i);
        int grey = ((color.getRed() + color.getBlue() + color.getGreen())/3);
        //System.out.println(grey);
        if (grey >= 237) {
            light++;
        } 
        else {
            dark++;                
        }           
    }
}

System.out.println(light); 
System.out.println(dark);
```

Comment: imagine pure red color (255, 0, 0)? is it light or dark one?

Comment: By light I mean closer to white and dark being closer to black. My terminology could be off. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No pro at this, but perhaps you should be looking at the "B" or brightness component of a Color's HSB representation and not the RGB representation.

Answer (score 0):

This as itself should work - pick up the color at location j i on the screen. Now if that location is covered by the image you intend is another issue we [here] dont' know what is in that spot. And if toGray() does some wierd transform that negates the image. So check these

```
for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
    Color color = robot.getPixelColor(j, i);
    int grey = ((color.getRed() + color.getBlue() + color.getGreen())/3);
    //System.out.println(grey);
    if (grey >= 237) {
        light++;
    } 
    else {
        dark++;                
    }           
}
```